# Line chart with large number of labels on X axis

Tags: chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to implement a Line chart.  The X axis of this chart has many points, for example the integer range 1 to 200.  Having this many points on the X axis causes an issue when displaying:

[image]

Is is possible to 'conflate' the labels so that I perhaps just show 1, 10, 20?  This should only impact the labels and not remove points from the plotted line itself.

Answer (score 4):

What I did was when generating the array for the labels, check if `i % 10 === 0` where `i` is the index of the label, if true, add the label to the array, if false, add empty string to the array.

Maybe not the cleanest way, but it works.